# Finding and replacing strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The app that I'm building allows users to store first and last names of contacts. First names are mandatory, but, last names aren't. In some cases they exist and in some cases they don't.

I tried using the following logic to replace LNAME with the last name of the contact.

```
def replace_names
   self.message.gsub! 'LNAME', contact.last_name
   self.message.gsub! 'FNAME', contact.first_name
   #METHOD 2    
   #h = {"FNAME" => contact.first_name,"LNAME" => contact.last_name}
   #self.message.gsub!(/\w+/) { |m| h.fetch(m,m)}
   #METHOD 3
   #self.message.gsub!(/[FNAMELNAME]/, 'FNAME' => 1, 'LNAME' => 2)
end
```

When both first and last names are present, the logic (uncommented one) works perfectly fine. However, when there is no last name, the results are all over the place. In some places the LNAME is displayed as LNAME and in some places it isn't shown.

I went through a few other SO solutions and they didn't work as expected when the last name is absent. I would really appreciate a suggestion.

Comment: Are the LNAMEs in another database column, text field, params, variable, etc? What is `self.message`? Just need a little more information in order to help.

Comment: @nikkon226 LNAME is another column in the DB and is a string. self.message refers to the message typed by a user in the text_area. Basically, it's like an email form/model that has contact dropdown, a subject line and the message area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `contact.last_name` is not present, you should replace 'LNAME' with an empty string

```
   self.message.gsub! 'LNAME', contact.last_name || ''
```